# On application launch show 2 different pages based on a condition?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Does anyone know how to show two different "first" pages on application launch based on some condition.

an example of this would be show a log in page when a user has not entered their password yet, but show the main page once the user has entered their password once before.

I see that you can set the default navigation page in WMAppManifest.xml (below), and I was looking into possibly creating my own PhoneApplicationFrame, but I am unsure how I should go about it.

```
<Tasks>
     <DefaultTask  Name ="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml"/>
</Tasks>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Peter Torr covers page redirections quite well here. Two methods are offered with relative merits covered.

[Redirecting an initial navigation - Peter Torr's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/redirecting-an-initial-navigation.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)

I'd also recommend familiarising with his accompanying post on places here.

[Introducing the concept of “Places” - Peter Torr's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/introducing-the-concept-of-places.aspx)

This address back stack handling (certification consideration) and addresses scenarios such as login pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ChildWindow to show a modal window with the login form ?

http://wildermuth.com/2010/08/17/Using_ChildWindow_in_Windows_Phone_7_Projects

I used one for a first time run of my application to set preferences.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your main page do nothing but check the condition and then forward the caller to the correct "start page" or you could build your main page in accordance with the condition.  The former seems like the easiest solution.

Comment: If you're not careful, you'll have problems with the former when users immediately click back when entering your app - it'll try to move to your initial "redirect page" which will just return users back to where they are, preventing users from exiting the app using the back button (besides being annoying, will probably fail your app from certification). The best thing would be to have some sort of condition detection on your first page, and then show the correct stuff depending on which "page" you want :)