# Windows Phone 7 Sign in screen redirect

Tags: windows-phone-7

Apologise if there is answer for this somewhere else, I can't find any.

I imagine this is a common situation. The first time the user runs the application I want them to be presented with the SignIn.xaml, if they don't have any saved details, else I just want to go straight to the MainPage.xaml.

I'd usually do this by sticking a check in the constructor of the MainPage and if they don't have details navigate away. The problem I have is that

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SignIn.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

is coming up as a null reference. What am I missing? Is there a proper way to do something like this in WP7?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately the WP7 navigation framework doesn't handle the "do something on first run" situation very nicely at all.

I suspect the problem you're seeing is that you don't have a `NavigationService` yet... but even if you did, you'd have a problem: the user could still hit the "back" button. You can't even work around that, because the user pressing back *should* exit the app... but there's no way I'm aware of for doing that without already being at the first page naturally when the user hits the back button.

The only workaround I've found for this is to have the "sign-in" view in the same page as the normal first page, and display one or the other conditionally. Yes, it sucks... but it's the only approach I've found which works. If you find another, I'll be happy to hear about it :)

Comment: Oh man that sucks! this is a very common task, I can't believe there's not a tidier way of doing this. But thanks for confirming what I thought.

Comment: Tried it. Works neat enough for now. If something better comes up then I can always change it

Comment: I had the same problem about not wanting to display the login page when the user hits the back button. What I did is store a global boolean that indicates whether the user has already logged in, then, within the `NavigatedTo` callback (I probably have the name wrong, typing from memory) for the login page I check the boolean and if the user is logged in I throw an exception which I make sure goes unhandled. This causes the app to quit. Ugly as sin, but the only thing I could think of, I'd love to hear of another way to do this.

Comment: @Praetorian: I'd expect that to potentially cause the app to fail validation, as you're not meant to let the app just quit. Maybe it works now, but I suspect it may well not always pass.

Comment: I don't know whether it will pass validation even now, I haven't submitted the app for validation yet :-). Problem is, if I were to do what you said I'd need to switch between 3 views on the first page. I already have a conditional 2 view first page for the very first time user launches the app and subsequent runs. I guess I'll have to add the 3rd view as well, just suck it up and maintain an enormous class

Comment: Has this improved at all in the time since this answer was posted?

Comment: @Schnapple: I haven't kept up with Mango I'm afraid, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6):

Peter Torr covers page redirections quite well here. Two methods are offered with relative merits covered. Edit: Note you can redirect to a login page, rather then employing the popup suggestion for login handling.

[Redirecting an initial navigation - Peter Torr's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/redirecting-an-initial-navigation.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)

I'd also recommend familiarising with his accompanying post on places here.

[Introducing the concept of “Places” - Peter Torr's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/introducing-the-concept-of-places.aspx)

This address back stack handling (certification consideration) and addresses scenarios such as login pages.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than have your main page navigate to a sign in page (which will upset you back stack). Either conditionally set the first page or have the login appear as a popup.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263039/on-application-launch-show-2-different-pages-based-on-a-condition) for more on the subject.

Comment: Yeah I've had a look at the solution. Not crazy about it and the popup is not viable as its a multi page login.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get Peter Torr's UriMapper approach to work with the separate login / welcome page. The main thing was changing the Uri of the UriMapper again after the login and then changing the query string when navigating back to MainPage.xaml after finishing with the login / welcome page. Otherwise when attempting to navigate to MainPage.xaml from the login page, nothing happened.

For more info and a sample project see http://www.geoffhudik.com/tech/2012/2/19/windows-phone-login-navigation.html. I welcome any thoughts and better suggestions.