# How to change screen's in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing an app in which the user register to EULA then only he proceeds and is navigated to next page, but still after registration the app starts with EULA not the navigated page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 7 Sign in screen redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303403/windows-phone-7-sign-in-screen-redirect)

Comment: It's a duplicate, but I'm not surprised you didn't find it :)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reviewing Peter Torr's advice with respect to navigation redirections and places.

[Introducing the concept of “Places” - Peter Torr's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/introducing-the-concept-of-places.aspx)

[Redirecting an initial navigation - Peter Torr's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/redirecting-an-initial-navigation.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)

This recent release may also be worth consideration.

[Solving Circular Navigation in Windows Phone Silverlight Applications](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/12/13/solving-circular-navigation-in-windows-phone-silverlight-applications.aspx)

Comment: Hi Mick,thanks for the reply to use Peter Torr's Blog, but having some problem with the UriMapper. The flaw is when i am navigating to my EULA page which navigates to first page which navigates to Main Page.xaml but, this navigates back to EULA.xaml, here i mapped the MainPage.xaml and toggled between EULA.xaml and MainPage.xaml. So, the problem is after EULA->firstpage->EULA but i want it like EULA->firstpage->MaiNPage. How to achive this? Regards, Panache

Comment: I'm not following that description, however I did add another link which may be worth a look.

Comment: Thanx Mick N, just what I needed

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following right, I'd do something like this:

Store a variable isEulaAccepted and then, in the Initializer method:

```
public EulaPage(){
  if(isEulaAccepted){
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/FirstPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

This might not be the best solution, but I hope it helps.